# PHP Session Suddenly Stopped Working For Some Pages

Tags: php, session

I've bumped into a strange glitch. I had no problems before but now suddenly the PHP session will only work for some pages but not others.

Here is how I use the session:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["account"])) {
    // session does not exist
    echo "<h1>session does not exist</h1>";
} else {    
    echo "<h1>session exists</h1>";
}
```

The same code does not longer work for some pages. For example I'm able to login just fine and use most of the tools for login. But when I created a new file `testSession.php` with the same content as shown above. It has lost the session for some reason.

I specifically used `ini_set('session.save_path', realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));` to solve a simmilar problem but now the problem is back... why?

The strange thing about all of this is that the one php script I wanted to trigger has worked before without a problem. What could be the issue here? Why does it suddnely not work for some pages/script, as far as I can tell I've never touched that part of the code, so I didn't even change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make a session.php file that you call in every page you need to access to sessions like:

**session.php**

```
  ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // secure cookie
  session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','localhost',true,true); // duration, path, domain, secure connection, httponly (secure js access)
  session_start(); // start session
  session_regenerate_id(); // regenerating for security issues
```

and then include this to your pages:

```
 include 'session.php';
 if(!isset($_SESSION["account"])) {
    echo "<h1>session does not exist</h1>";
 } else {    
    echo "<h1>session exists</h1>";
  }
```

Comment: But why did it work before? I haven't changed anything..

Comment: I don’t understand what u just said, it works now or not?

Comment: No it didn't work.. I've tried again to pin point any difference between the script that worked and the one that did not work anymore. After redoing everything I ended up with the same script as before but for some reason, now suddenly it works.. But I've literally not changed anything.. this is very strange.. I don not know what the problem was..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u start session on every page. If you have it dynamicly, make sure that your require 'xxx'; is right. Then try deleting you phpsessionid in webdevelopment tools in chrome. At last, restart your local server - wamp, xampp etc.